# Difference in time between list append and + operator that I can't explain

Tags: python, list, append, concatenation

I'm trying to use `time.clock()` in Python 3.4 on Windows 7 to compare the speed of `append` and `+=`. (It's an exercise from Chapter 10 of Think Python.) Here's my code:

```
import time
fin = open('words.txt')
print("Comparing the time it takes to make a list with append vs. the + operator")

timeConcatStart = time.clock()
wordsList = []
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    wordsList += word
timeConcatEnd = time.clock()
concatElapsed = timeConcatEnd - timeConcatStart
print("+ operator took ",concatElapsed,"seconds for words.txt")

timeAppendStart = time.clock()
wordList = []
for line in fin:
    word = line.strip()
    wordList.append(word)
timeAppendEnd = time.clock()
appendElapsed = timeAppendEnd - timeAppendStart
print("Append took ",appendElapsed,"seconds for words.txt")
```

On my system, I got that the `+` operator took about 0.2 seconds and `append` took 0.002 seconds.

When I switch the order so the append code block is first, the `append` now takes 0.2 seconds and it's the `+` operator that takes 0.002 seconds.

If I copy and paste the code, both get faster, with the "third" block taking ~8e-5 seconds and the "fourth" taking ~4e5. Then if I copy and paste again, both take about 5e-5 seconds. Even more confusingly, if I get rid of all the copied and pasted code, and then just change the second occurence of the variable name wordsList to otherList, it's actually *faster* for otherList. I.e., the times I get then are 0.2 seconds for the first block but ~5e-5 for the second.

Why does the first loop always take the longest? Does the `open` object load the `words.txt` file into memory and then just keep it there for the next time I need it? I thought there was an implicit "close".

Or does it have nothing to do with the file I/O but instead have something to do with the memory allocated to the list? I.e., is it because I "pre-allocated" wordsList in the first loop and then just wrote over it in the second? I tried changing the variable name to test that hypothesis and then I got a shorter time.

Finally, how would you test/debug these ideas? Should I be inserting print statements to get the variable's addresses or something? Obvs I'm a debug noob.
Please feel free to correct any terminology faux pas I made and thanks for any help

Comment: `+=` doesn't append to the list, it **extends** the list. `listobj += stringobj` adds *each individual character separately*; it is equivalent to `listobj.extend(stringobj)`, or `for character in stringobj: listobj.append(character)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's happening here is that you *exhausted the file object*. A file object uses a *current file position* to read the next bytes from the file, and looping over a file reads from the file until the end.

Your second loop then yields *no results* as the file is still at the end position. You could use `fin.seek(0)` before your second `for line in fin:` loop to start reading from the beginning of the file again, but there are other problems here.

You are more testing how fast the OS and your hardware can deliver file data; when benchmarking always remove outside factors as much as you can. The OS will cache read file data in memory for a while, for example, which will certainly skew the results.

Another problem is that you are running each approach just once, leaving your benchmark wide open to other biases; other processes on your computer running take time too and may unfairly affect the outcome.

To avoid such biases, Python comes with a benchmarking module called [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) that avoids the pitfalls by running a test *many, many times* (the default is 1 million), by picking the most accurate timing mechanism for your OS, and by disabling potential biases such as the garbage collection system. You should give it the exact same test data at the start (in memory, not from a file).

Last but not least, you are comparing the wrong things. `+=` is not the same as `list.append()`. Here, `+=` is functionally equivalent to `list.extend()`; the list is extended with each element from the added sequence added separately, *not* as a single element:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst += 'foobar'
>>> lst
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r']
>>> lst.append('foobar')
>>> lst
['f', 'o', 'o', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'foobar']
```

As such, `list.append()` is going to be faster, as only a single element at a time is added in that case:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> timeit('lst.append(value)', 'lst = []; value = "foobar"')
0.07227020798018202
>>> timeit('lst += value', 'lst = []; value = "foobar"')
0.15380392200313509
```

The first test adds the string `'foobar'` 1 million times to `lst`, while the second grows the list by adding the individual elements `'f'`, `'o'`, `'o'`, `'b'`, `'a'`, and `'r'` a million times. Not surprisingly, the second test runs at less than half the speed.

If you want to use `+=` to add **one** element to the list, you need to wrap that one element in another sequence; a singleton list object, for example:

```
>>> timeit('lst += [value]', 'lst = []; value = "foobar"')
0.14356198499444872
```

This is still much slower than using `list.append()`, but at least now you are achieving the same end result.